# Getting midpoint of rectangle polygon lines on shortest lines and saving as points using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I'm trying to understand ArcPy. My first task is to put a point at each end of a trench.
Each trench is a polygon, a rectangle, the points therefore should be located at the midpoint of the two shorter ends and be named after the trench ID with `.1` or `.2` appended. So for trench ID=Tr1 two points are appended to a points feature class (let's call it `tr_points`). If the points are from `Tr1` then the 1st point has id=1.1 and the 2nd point has id=1.2 etc.

I can list all the points in the polygon by polygon:

```
rows=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("trenches","Shape@")
for row in rows:
    print(row)
    for polygon in row[0]:
        for point in polygon:
            print (point)
```

But then I can also use the below

```
rows=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("trenches","Shape@")
for Feature in rows:
    midpoint = Feature.shape.positionAlongLine(0.50,True).firstPoint
    print(midpoint.X)
    print(midpoint.Y)
```

With a midpoint calculated per length I need to discard the mid points for the longest lengths (or keep the points from the 2 shortest lengths).

Give the points the id of the trench and append `.1` or `.2` to this value (the order in which this happens does not matter) and append this point to the `tr_points` feature class.

Any pointers, since the above is rather vague?

Comment: Your points-in-polygon sample code only handles single-part polygons without interior rings. If you really only have quadrilaterals that are very nearly rectangular it should be simple to calculate the length of the first two segments, then calculate the midpoint of the first and third or second and fourth segments. This, then, follows the "SearchCursor nested in InsertCursor" pattern common to many (if not most) geoprocessing tools.

Comment: All polygons are 50m by 2m but can be in various orientations.

Answer (score 4):

I show you a solution using ModelBuilder, you can convert that to code if you wish. The first model prepares the data:

[image: Prepare data]

Prepared data

[image: Prepared data]

Next model requires an iterator to drive the processing based upon the ID field

[image: Processing model]

The end result being:

[image: Results]

The processing model takes advantage of the fact that tools honour selections so when the generate near tool is run its only looking at the current trench centroid and edge midpoints. The selection, subsequent switch and then subset is to over come the fact that even though you start with a selection this is overwritten because of the selection on the joined data and you have to deal with all the other midpoints in the same dataset.

Finally the +1 is to overcome rounding issues as my test data is in the many metres in size +1 was ok for me, if your trench's are just a few metres then experiment with +0.5 or whatever works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ponder over this approach, but I'm specifically looking for a python approach (I know geoprocessing>results allows export of python code, but I'm also trying to understand the api)

Comment: The model describes the work flow and tools you need to use to solve your particular problem, you could use a model or code it in python as you have started. I've just given you one such approach.